# Can a .m be exported from an iPhone app?

Tags: objective-c

We recently deleted a .m from an iphone app in XCODE under development. We have a few phones around the office running the app. Is there a way to recover the .m file from the phone or is it not possible from the compiled app?

Comment: Obligatory source code version control comment.

Comment: You don't have a backup of your source?!?!?!

Comment: Yeah I know... bad bad bad...

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible from the compiled App.   The `.m` file is a source file and is never sent to the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you're not going to get the .m back. You can use something like otool to get the symbols exposed to the runtime (Objective-C being as reflective as it is) and the ARM assembly that comprises each individual method, from which you could in theory reconstruct something but it'll look nothing like your original code.